# ASP.NET MVC 2 : Having trouble with creating a Master-Detail View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, model, renderpartial, master-detail

I'm having trouble right now with the creation of a Master-Detail page in an ASP.NET MVC 2 project at the moment. This project uses Entity Framework OR/M for table mapping. I'm using a custom ***CategoryModel*** which is passing another list of objects. I've simplified the *Model* for presentation purposes :

```
    public class CategoryModel {
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CategoryDescription> CategoryDescriptions { get; set; }
    }
```

***CategoryDescription*** is a collection of "culture language-based" descriptions for each ***Category***.

I'm passing the ***CategoryModel*** to my controller [Again, the controller *Edit* method has been simplified for presentation purposes] :

```
        // CategoryModel constructor
        CategoryModel categoryModel = new CategoryModel()
        {
            Category = (from c in bo.Categories where c.CategoryID == categoryId select c) as Category,
            CategoryDescriptions = bo.CategoryDescriptions.Where(p => p.CategoryID == categoryId).OrderBy(p => p.Language == "en")
        };
        return View(categoryModel);
```

After that, I'm sending over the data to my view, which in turn will try to render a **PartialView** for each ***CategoryDescription*** I have. This is where I **fail** [Only part of the view is shown, the part showing the ***Category*** object is just fine] :

```
        <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<InnVue.Globe.Models.CategoryModel>" %>
    <%@ Import Namespace="InnVue.Globe.Models" %>

    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
        <%: ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"] %> Category
    </asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2><%: ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"] %> Category</h2>

    <% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
        <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>CategoryDescription</legend>
            <% foreach (var catdes in Model.CategoryDescriptions) { %>
                <% Html.RenderPartial("CategoryDescriptions", catdes); %>
            <% } %>
            <% Html.RenderPartial("CategoryDescriptions", Model.CategoryDescriptions, new ViewDataDictionary()); %>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    <% } %>

    <div>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

The problem I'm having right now comes from the ***RenderPartial*** method, which crash my application every single time I've tried to pass data over it.

I did try to change the Inherits tag to several types, didn't seem to solve the problem. If I don't pass any data using the ***RenderPartial*** *htmlhelper* method, the page loads just fine.

I've tried several suggestions over forum boards, but I couldn't find an answer to solve this problem. The only restriction I have here for pulling the data in the ***PartialView*** over is to not use the ***ViewData***[] dictionary from my company for many obvious reasons.

Thanks for your time people, and sorry for my English, I'm a native french speaker from Canada, if any typos sorry in advance !

EDIT 01/10 : The reason why there's one ***RenderPartial*** outside the loop is for a new input box for adding description content, but there's logic in the postback *edit* method of my controller to take care of this. the ***RenderPartial*** inside the loop is there to let the user edit existing descriptions of that category. Starting to make the loop work is the key here, I've only made a scaffolded ***PartialView*** for test purposes, I can't even load an empty "

Hello World

" if I pass data to the ***PartialView***. I'll add in code of the ***PartialView***, even if I'm not sure of which class it should inherit :

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<InnVue.Globe.Models.CategoryModel>" %>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>
        <p>Hello World !</p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

<% } %>

<div>
    <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
</div>
```

Comment: You have all kinds of problems here.  You cannot have a form inside of another form, and you cannot pass a partial view a datatype it is not designed to handle.  Your partial view is also of the same type as your main view.  Your partial view needs to be of type `CategoryDescription` and you need to remove the second render partial and implement it another way.

Comment: Thanks Nick, it helped a lot ! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks *NickLarsen* for your help, your comment helped me figure out what I was doing wrong.

***The inheritance of my partial view*** was the cause of the problem.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<InnVue.Globe.Models.CategoryDescription>" %>
```

Was the solution to my problem, I didn't really understood strongly-typed views, and it led me to wander around aimlessly ^^'

As for the double *RenderPartial* in my ***Edit*** View, this is needed, as I want to have a new field for new data entry no matter if there's already data rows on ***CategoryDescription*** or not.

Here's the final fieldset, for those who are wondering how I've done my *Master-Detail* form :

```
        <fieldset>
        <legend>CategoryDescription</legend>
        <% foreach (var catdes in Model.CategoryDescriptions) { %>
            <% Html.RenderPartial("CategoryDescription", catdes); %>
        <% } %>
        <% 
            CategoryDescription emptyCatDes = new CategoryDescription();
            Html.RenderPartial("CategoryDescription", emptyCatDes, new ViewDataDictionary()); %>
    </fieldset>
```

I don't know yet if it's 100% effective, but all the information is showing up correctly right now in my *View*.

Good luck to everyone, thanks again for the help *NickLarsen* !

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are calling the same render partial method twice, passing it once with the datatype `CategoryDescription` and another time passing it a model with type `IEnumerable<CategoryDescription>`.  Have you tried commenting out the one that does not pass the correct data type for the view?

Try something like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<InnVue.Globe.Models.CategoryModel>" %>
    <%@ Import Namespace="InnVue.Globe.Models" %>

    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
        <%: ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"] %> Category
    </asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2><%: ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"] %> Category</h2>

    <% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
        <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>CategoryDescription</legend>
            <% foreach (var catdes in Model.CategoryDescriptions) { %>
                <% Html.RenderPartial("CategoryDescriptions", catdes); %>
            <% } %>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    <% } %>

    <div>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

And use this as your partial view:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<InnVue.Globe.Models.CategoryModel>" %>

<%: Html.EditorFor(m => m) %>
```